# Apache add ServerAlias without restart

Tags: apache

I have a virtualhost in httpd.conf

like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/project/web >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
    </Directory>
     ServerName project.com
     ServerAlias *.project.com 
     ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/project/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

now on this vhost i want to catch several domains, i have built software that replaces the ServerAlias line like for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/project/web >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
    </Directory>
     ServerName project.com
     ServerAlias *.project.com foo.bar.com bar.foo.com foo.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/project/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

unfortunatly the webserver must be restarted to apply the new configuration.

I read about mod_vhost_alias but thats not what i´m looking for, i dont want to add new vhosts i just want that new ServerAliases to be applied.

Any thoughts further than graceful restart ?

Comment: I am afraid you would need to restart the server if you want that to take effect

Comment: Maybe this should help - http://serverfault.com/questions/92139/how-can-i-configure-virtualhost-without-restarting-apache-web-server

Comment: @OndřejŠotek thanks, but unfortunatly i dont have a directory per vhost, and i only need one vhost, only the ServerAliases increase / decrease

Comment: i know this is after really long time, did you mange to solve this

Comment: @irshad2809 never solved that and sticked to `httpd graceful` without noticing any errors, only bad point is that you need more permissions to do so